# Convert anonymous type T to strong type

Tags: c#, .net

How can I convert an anonymous type T to strong type class

I have this class that has two in parameters as anonymous type T. The method should sometime take any type of parameters.

I have tried using var `rest = pointOfSalesList.ChangeType(model, typeof(List<PointOfSaleModel>));` No errors is receipt but the variable `pointOfSalesList` is not converted to a strong type of `List<PointOfSaleModel>`.

```
internal override void Load<T>(T data, List<T> model)
{
    // this does't work
    var pointOfSalesList = Convert.ChangeType(model, typeof(List<PointOfSaleModel>));
}
```

I want to convert the `List<T> model` parameter to a strong type of class

```
internal class PointOfSaleModel : IPointOfSaleModel
    {
        public Guid PointOfSaleProviderUniqueId { get; set; }

        public string CorporateId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Adress { get; set; }

        public int? ZipCode { get; set; }

        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public string ContactPerson { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public bool Status { get; set; }
    }
```

I been trying for a day to solve this problem.

Comment: Why are you trying to change the type? This doesn't look like an appropriate solution; perhaps you should change T to be an `IPointOfSaleModel` and remove the type parameters?

Comment: `T` is not _anonymous_, it's _generic_, meaning it could be ANY type (since there are no explicit restrictions)  What if `T` is `int`?  How would you "convert" that to `PointOfSaleModel`?

Comment: what are you trying to do in the conversion in `Load()`?

Comment: Please provide an example that includes an actual list of `T`, and explain why you create instances of an anonymous type with `select new { ... }` instead of directly instantiating the strongly typed class you seem to actually need as `select new PointOfSaleModel() { ....}`.

Comment: When is it appropriate to use T

Comment: @eFlag `T` is just a name.  If you mean when is it appropriate to use generics, it's when a method or class is designed to work with *any possible type* without caring what it is.  For example, a `List` is generic because you can create a list of *anything*, and the definition of the list doesn't care what type it's working on; it can work with *any* type.

Comment: @eFlag "When is it appropriate to use T" When your method works regardless of what `T` is. You can restrict `T` to some extent (force it to be a class, implement a particular interface, have a parameterless constructor, etc.) but if your method only works with one type then is it not "generic".

Comment: I used List<T> because sometime i have List<PointOfSaleModel>, sometime List<CardProvider>, and so on. I thought the best way was to use List<T> in order to just have one method that does it all.

Comment: @eFlag The problem with that design is that `<T>` implies a **generic** parameter, meaning I could pass to your method anything there. (I.e. `Load<MemoryStream>(ms, new List<MemoryStream>())`. In cases where the method (`Load`, in this case) is working on specific *assumptions* of an object, you should implement a common `Interface` between all the classes/structures/etc, and use that `Interface` as the type.

Comment: @eFlag, could you show us an example of how you intended to use this. Including a few examples of the actual content of  the `model` list and `data` arguments used in calls to your `Load` function?

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this?

```
internal override void Load<T>(T data, List<T> model)
{

    if (data.GetType() == typeof(PointOfSaleModel))
        {
            var pointOfSalesList = model as List<PointOfSaleModel>;
        }            
}
```

Comment: Your safely checking the type before performing a cast of PointOfSaleModel

Comment: This will work only if T is _exactly_ `PointOfSaleModel` (and not a subclass)), in which case it should not be generic.

Comment: D Stanley. Then better way is to use strongly type as parameter instead?

Comment: @eFlag Is the list being passed in *actually* a list of `PointOfSaleModel` objects?  If so, yes.

Answer (score 0):

This code shows the casting without any tricks but enforcing generics (notice where T:PointOfSaleModel )

```
class Caster
{
    internal void Load<T>(List<T> model)
        where T:PointOfSaleModel
    {

        // this should work
        var pointOfSalesList = new List<PointOfSaleModel>(model);
    }

}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<PointOfSaleModel> {
            new PointOfSaleModel{
                Name = "name 1"
            }
        };
        var caster = new Caster ();
        caster.Load (list);
    }
}
```